# Simple way to add line to Ubuntu bashrc

Tags: bash

I am just starting my journey with Ubuntu and I am having a problem getting sound from my speakers when using the line in.  I have been entering the following in the terminal every time I log in or reboot =  `pactl load-module module-loopback`

I am not familiar with editing a bashrc file so I was wondering is there a simple way to achieve it?

Comment: whenever you ask a question, think if it might have been asked / answered before on the internet. Otherwise the internet storage is full in a few years

Comment: You may want to consider adding it to `~/.profile` (or `./.bash_profile` depending on distribution) so that it is only run once with a login shell and not ever time you open a new terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way for me is with the command:

```
echo "pactl load-module module-loopback" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution then `echo` is `printf` because it adds the return line.

#### Solution

```sh
printf "\n%s\n" "pactl load-module module-loopback" >> ~/.profile
source ~/.profile
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the easiest an simplest way I and many other developers would do it

```
echo "pactl load-module module-loopback" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score -1):

Found an easy way to achieve my goal - loaded a program called Alsa Mixer which lets you configure all the input/output settings, set it up exactly as I needed then set Alsa Mixer to boot with my startup progs - works perfectly.